# Strip the last occurrence of numbers inside braces from a string

Tags: python

I would like to know how to strip the last occurrence of ( ) and its content if only numbers/digits inside given a string.

The below code strips all the ( ) in a string.

```
 import regex
    s1 = "( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED ( 23 )"
    s2 = "( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED  ( closed )"
    res = regex.sub(r'\s*(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))$', '', s1)
    res = regex.sub(r'\s*(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))$', '', s2)
    print(res)
```

This will remove content inside string but i wanted to remove only digit or numbers inside ( ) which appears at last of string

output:

```
 s1 = "( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED ( 23 )"
 s2 = "( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED  ( closed )"
```

Comment: I am a little confused, can you share the expected output

Comment: Is the final parens always at the end of the string? That makes the problem much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` with a negative lookahead assertion which rules out any other term `(...)` occurring after the last match.

```
s1 = "( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED ( 23 )"
s2 = "( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED  ( closed )"
out1 = re.sub(r'\(\s*\d+\s*\)(?!.*\([^)]*\))', '', s1)
out2 = re.sub(r'\(\s*\d+\s*\)(?!.*\([^)]*\))', '', s2)
print(out1)
print(out2)
```

This prints:

```
( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED 
( 2,2,2) (GREATER) MINDS LIMITED  ( closed )
```